# Jquery close event- Promotional/Navigation banner

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session-cookies

I am creating a Promotional banner which is supposed to be seen on all the pages of the website. This banner is displayed above the header. 
It has a close button. If anyone closes the banner it should not be displayed again on any page for that user.
If the browser is closed and opened again the banner must be displayed. 
I have tried different ways (window.unload,beforeunload etc ) but it still does not work as per my requirement. 
If I close the banner it appears back on page refresh[or when a new link is opened] if I use "beforeunload".

Following is my code which I wrote for hiding banner for 1 hour if it is closed. 
What I actually need is hiding it till the browser-tab is closed.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    console.log("UNLOADING");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/krina1810/3gtdunet/8/

Comment: The behavior you're describing requires cookies (as it appears you know, given the tags). What cookies did you set?

Comment: Cookie which I used here is 'nav', I have also tried using session id as cookie.  
Cookies.set('<?php echo session_id(); ?>',"true" , {
   expires: date,
   path: '/'
  });

Comment: If you don't plan to target old browsers, [window.sessionStorage (doc from MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) can be a good solution, it's simple to use, and you won't have to unset the value because it is cleared when browser closes (conveniently for you). By the way, just as a notice, all the relevant code should be in the question itself, as links can break

Comment: Wow thank you so much @ka

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/krina1810/e0jgdvod/   -> updated code...it works as per the requirement now ... Thanks again @Kaddath